# Requesting API data using getStaticProps() returns undefined object | Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, next.js

I'm new to new to nextjs.
I'm making a real estate web using [bayut API](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/bayut/).
And got trouble requesting agencies data from the API. I want to show list of agencies on my page like so:
[ss taken from bayut.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObGkT.png)

index.js:

```
import { baseUrl, fetchApi } from "../utils/fetchApi";

export default function Agency({ agencyList }) {
  console.log({ agencyList }); // <====I need this
  return <div>aaa</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  //Fetch agencies list
  const agencyList = await fetchApi(
    `${baseUrl}/agencies/list?hitsPerPage=25&page=0&lang=en`
  );
  return {
    props: {
      agencyList: agencyList?.hits,
    },
  };
}
```

fetchApi.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const baseUrl = "https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com";

export const fetchApi = async (url) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "bayut.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAPIDAPI_KEY,
    },
  });
  return data;
};
```

In console returns:

> {agencyList: undefined}agencyList:
>
> > undefined[[Prototype]]: Object

While It will return property object as it should if I change the url to:

```
/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=1
```

it will return:

> agencyList: Array(1)}
>
> > agencyList: Array(1)
> >
> > > 0: {id: 2828151, ownerID: 1101619, userExternalID: '1101619', sourceID: 1, state: 'active', …}
> > > length: 1

I'm expecting to return similar kind of data as the property object. I also tried to copy the code from the API page but no luck:

2nd index.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Agency = () => {
  const [agentList, setAgentList] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com/agencies/list",
    params: { hitsPerPage: "25", page: "0", lang: "en" },
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "bayut.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAPIDAPI_KEY,
    },
  };

  const fetchAgentList = async () => {
    const response = await axios.request(options);
    setAgentList(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAgentList();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(agentList);
  }, [agentList]);

  return <div>aaa</div>;
};

export default Agency;
```

It returns an empty array:

> []
>
> > length: 0

[Question 1]Any idea how to solve this? Am I missing any parameter? Also above code wont return any error message but, if I create a new page, named `localhost:3000/agency`, and copy the `index.js` code to `agency.js`, it will run to this error message:

> **Server Error**
> Error: Error serializing `.agencyList` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/agency".
> Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

Even requesting property object (which works on `index.js`) it won't work on `agency.js` page.[Question 2] Does it means I can only use getStaticProps() on `/` page only (why this happend)? or do I need to initialize something?

Sorry for messy post. first time posting. Thankyou!

**tl;dr** A real estate web requesting API data. getStaticProps() works on property object but not on agency object. what am I missing here?

Comment: what happen when u access the url directly?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I'm not sure what you mean. Can you tell me more specific please?

Comment: what happen when u access `/agencies/list?hitsPerPage=25&page=0&lang=en` directly (e.g. with curl). did it give u results you want?

Comment: `-H` should be the same as what u use for fetch, e.g. `-H "x-rapidapi-host: bayut.p.rapidapi.com" -H "x-rapidapi-key: yourApikey"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, I just need to add `query: '{some word}'` into the parameter. It is stated on rapidApi page that the paramater is `optional` but I guess I couldn't make request without it.